# opening a jpeg or png image as pixel data in c or c++

Tags: c++, c, image

this is my first post so please let me know if i dont relay the question clearly.

i am trying to open a (black and white) jpeg or png image file as an array in dev c++ so that i can isolate the place of the white pixels. the pointers, and loops for the isolation i understand. however, opening the image file has not worked and have been unable to find an example that i can use. besides the given 
    #include "cstdlib"
    #include "iostream"
    #include "stdio.h"

i have no other header files.
i know fopen for file open, however none of my attempts have displayed the data of the image.

thank you for any help

THIS IS NOT MY CODE. THIS IS BIV1991 EXAMPLE PROVIDED TO ME
i am posting because the header for gdiplus.h is not being located. the header unknwn, windows,objidl were suggested to solve that problem

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment(lib,"gdiplus.lib") 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // initialize gdiplus
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput si;
ULONG_PTR token;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token,&si,0);

// load image as bitmap, any formats supported
Gdiplus::Bitmap image(L"C:\\image.jpg",false);
int w = image.GetWidth();
// image.LockBits - to read pixels 
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Both of those formats are encoded so you would need to decode them to get at the raw data.  You should look into a library to handle the decoding.

Comment: There's nothing for decoding images built into standard C++. You need a third-party library for that, such as [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) and [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Comment: that makes perfect sense. im having troble including that library however. would you be able to show me the proper include statement? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, there is no standard C++ library to process images. Secondly, jpeg and png image formats are compressed image formats that need some complex sort of decompressing algorithm. So to start work with images you have two ways:

1. Using of simple image format like bmp. bmp is just pixel buffer
   with some light header, describing that pixel buffer format. You can
   write a program loading bmp in half an our on your own (and waste
   about an hour to understand the format itself). More on bmp:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format.
2. Using EXTERNAL
       library. That is, you don't have this library with your language or
       compiler package. You need to download and even install it
       sometimes. In general, to use external library you need to do five
       thighs: 1) Find image processing library in Internet. 2) Put xxx.lib file in your project folder. 3) Tell your linker you want to use xxx.lib 4) Add in your code #include "xxx.h". 5) Use library API to load image.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. i usually work with ardino and have never had to download outside header files like that from the internet. originally i was doing this project with a Psoc 4 microcontroller with a external camera and sd card. however, along with working with a less mastered code (cyperss's own) i was having worlds of errors getting libs to work. i wanted to use a c++ model to show myself and the professor that the concept worked but the board we were experimenting on was not practicle past taking a picture and saving it on the sd card

Comment: If you use microcontrollers and even can't use some standard libraries (that is in my case, for example, I also work with microcontrollers), I can recommend you to use stb_image library. It has only stb_image.h and stb_image.cpp files, can process all common kids of images and has very low lever c-style pointer interface, so it's easy to integrate in microcontroller project.

Comment: thank you very much for that suggestion. i will try that. is there a internet link that you could give for this lib so that i can try and link it to the code?

Comment: I found now it on GitHub: https://github.com/nothings/stb . But it seems it was modifided since I last used it. Now all code is in stb_image.h file it seems and you need only that file.

Comment: this is a very cool web page. i looked over what was included and must say my professor will like this as well. i do have just one more question for you if its not to much trouble. how does one include a lib from the internet? do i put the url in my project file?

Comment: It depends on your IDE. But in general you need to download all lib files manually, put them in project directory and tell your compiler you want to use them.

Comment: It's Ok. Do not hesitate to choose my answer and close this topic. :)

Answer (score 2):

If You programming for Windows, You may use GDIPlus for reading of Jpeg and another images types and operates with them, for example **drawing** or getting of they pixels. Guarantee 100%. I was do it many times.

Whats to **include**:

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"gdiplus.lib")
```

What to do in **code**:

```
// initialize gdiplus
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput si;
ULONG_PTR token;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token,&si,0);

// load image, any formats supported
Gdiplus::Bitmap image(L"C:\\image.jpg",false);
int w = image.GetWidth();
// image.LockBits - to read pixels
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. however, i am getting a error for including it. i included it as both GDIplus.h and gdiplus.h

Comment: i believe you. i am still having an error read gdiplus:no such file or directory found. i believe it is something i am doing or the software i am using. i am using dev c++ with a windows 7 laptop. i will post your example in full so you can see what i did wrong. again thank you very much

Comment: Just use: Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012, and all will be OK ☻☻☻, it is very cool IDE.

Comment: just not download 2013 version! it is for Win8!

Comment: oops, 2013 version not bad, but only if you need programming for windows. I'm sorry, I'm confused with the 2015 version.